# Select more than 65,536 characters from nvarchar(max) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, varchar, nvarchar

I'm using `nvarchar(max)` for a column in a SQL Server table to store a document. It's usually not too large, but sometimes the documents exceed 65,536 characters. When it does, a select statement give a truncated out put to 65,536 characters. If I do something like,

```
select payload 
from [table] 
where id = 'someid' 
for xml path
```

Then I get the whole document, but inside an XML wrapper. Is there a way to select the whole contents of the column without it being truncated, and as a regular string, not in XML? Or am I just missing how this kind of thing is meant to be handled in SQL Server.

Comment: This is nothing to do with SQL Server, and to do with SSMS. If you are dealing with such large values, stop copy and pasting them out of SSMS' Grid Results. Use a proper ETL process.

Comment: Right click, press Query Options / Grid / Maximum Characters Retrieved. Or use SQLcmd or something like that

Comment: @Charlieface 65,536 is the maximum that SSMS Grid results support.

Comment: This also happens in the applications I'm running, which is Dell Boomi (so I don't know the specific implementation). I specify a select query and it's truncated.

Comment: If you don't want the XML wrapper then why are you using `for xml path`?

Comment: Because it doesn't truncate the message to 65,536 characters. If I do a regular select, it truncates the value to 65,536 characters.